# how to use dcc.loading to a tab with dataTable

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a tab with DataTable. I am trying to use dcc.Loading() to the DataTable to see rendering and it didn't work.  Thanks for your help.

Here is my code:

```
    well_table = DataTable(
        id="well-table", 
        columns=columns,
        data=data,
        derived_virtual_data=data,)
    
    well_table_loading=dcc.Loading( 
                                id='loading-well-table',
                                type='default',
                                children=well_table     # wrap contour in loading's children
                                )
    well_tab=dcc.Tab(
            well_table_loading,
            label=label,
            value=value,
            id='well-tab")
```

in callback

```
@app.callback(
    [
    Output("well-tab", "children"),
    ],
    [
    Input('load-area-data','n_clicks'),
    ],
    [
     State('date-range','start_date'),
     State('date-range','end_date'),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True,  
)
def change_area_data(n_clicks,start_date,end_date):  
     
   
    datatable_thisarea=DataTable(
        id="well-table", 
        columns=columns,
        data=data,
        derived_virtual_data=data,)

        
    return [datatable_thisarea]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are triggering the callback, you are overwriting the loading component with a datatable. You should wrap the tab with a loading since you are returning the datatable to the tab component and that needs to load since it's the output of the callback.

Comment: yes Daniel, it works. Thank you, but this way the tab name disappear. how do i keep tab name an its style? Thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel, would you mind advising me how to make tab name appear after using dcc.loading applied to tab? Thanks

Comment: Rather than applying the loading to the tab, apply it to a child div of it, this way should ensure the tab is still there and only its child will have a spinner

Comment: Thanks Daniel, tab's child is DataTable, that is why I was using dcc.loading to datatable only. or maybe I could just update datatable values and use datatable as output in callback? It has data and columns, and derivated_virtual_data, do I need to update all these items of datatable?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I got it work now, so I applied dcc.loading to datatable instead of tab as I did originally, now I just update columns and data of DataTable, like this @app.callback(
    [
    Output("well-table", "columns"),
    Output("well-table", "data"),]